# Cannot install npm package canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm

I've been trying to install the npm package [canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) all day. I ran:

```
sudo npm install canvas
```

but i get:

```
canvas@1.2.4 install /home/mark/Programming/canvas_npm/node_modules/canvas

node-gyp rebuild
make: Entering directory /home/mark/Programming/canvas_npm/node_modules/canvas/build' SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:0: ../src/Canvas.h:22:17: fatal error: nan.h: No such file or directory #include <nan.h> ^ compilation terminated. make: *** [Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o] Error 1 make: Leaving directory/home/mark/Programming/canvas_npm/node_modules/canvas/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/mark/Programming/canvas_npm/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.2.4 install: node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.2.4 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/mark/Programming/canvas_npm/npm-debug.log
```

The specific problem causing the error appears to be:

```
fatal error: nan.h: No such file or directory
```

I have installed Cairo using homebrew. I ideas why i cannot install canvas?

Answer (score 1):

My solution (for Ubuntu) was to install the nan package:

```
npm install nan
```

Then copy the nan headers to `/usr/include/`

```
sudo cp node_modules/nan/nan*.h /usr/include/
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its an issue with canvas version 1.2.24. I solved by installing  1.2.23